# Error 403 when trying to create a user group

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, cloud, confluence-rest-api

Im using confluence cloud and i try to create new User group

```
const bodyData2 = {
        "name": "RS-managers"
      };
    AP.request({ url: "/rest/api/group", 
        type: 'PUT',
        contentType: "application/json",
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: "bWJvdWF6emEuc3BlY3RydW1ncm91cGVAZ21haWwuY29tOnd6UGhpRXBWd1JTN0E0aDhrRVRyODhGRg==",
        data: JSON.stringify(bodyData2),
        success: function (data) { 
            console.log(data)
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

Comment: How do u get your Authorization token and where are you requesting ?

Comment: <email>:API_token from https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens       and i convert that for base 64

Comment: all scopes are added into atlassian-connecy.json                                                   "scopes": [
    "READ",
    "ACT_AS_USER",
    "WRITE",
    "DELETE",
    "SPACE_ADMIN",
    "ADMIN"
  ],

Comment: im requesting to <mydomain>atlassian.net/rest/api/group